# design issue in dynamic control creation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an dynamic controls I have an drop down with options   “Textbox, checkbox, dropdown, label” when user selects any of these options from the drop down controls gets created

Let me say I create control like these from selecting the option from the dropdown.

```
1: text box 
2: drop down 
3: text box:
4: dropdown
```

However in the page output its shown like this:

```
1: textbox
2: textbox
3: dropdown
4: dropdown
```

This is not the right order based on the selected order above.

**Issue here is the design is not quite right.**

When I am recreating the controls I recreate controls accoring to their types: TextBoxes, then DropDowns

**Pls find attched code  any suggestion how to solve this would be helpful.**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Dynamiccontrol.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dynamic_controls.Dynamiccontrol" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcontrols" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ddlDynamic_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Textbox</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Dropdown</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Dynamic_controls
{
    public partial class Dynamiccontrol : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Panel pnlTextBox;
        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create a Dynamic Panel
            pnlTextBox = new Panel();
            pnlTextBox.ID = "pnlTextBox";
            pnlTextBox.BorderWidth = 1;
            pnlTextBox.Width = 800;
            pnlTextBox.Height = 800;
            this.form1.Controls.Add(pnlTextBox);

            RecreateTxtControls("txtDynamic", "TextBox");
            RecreateDDLControls("ddlDynamic", "DropDownList");
            RecreateChkControls("chkDynamic", "CheckBox");

        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private int FindOccurence(string substr)
        {
            string reqstr = Request.Form.ToString();
            return ((reqstr.Length - reqstr.Replace(substr, "").Length) / substr.Length);
        }

    private int FindOccurenceCheckbox(string substr)
    {
        string reqstr = Request.Form.ToString();
        substr = "chkDynamic";
        return ((reqstr.Length - reqstr.Replace(substr, "").Length) / substr.Length);
    }

    private int FindOccurenceLabel(string substr)
    {
        string reqstr = Request.Form.ToString();
        substr = "lblDynamic";
        return ((reqstr.Length - reqstr.Replace(substr, "").Length) / substr.Length);
    }


    private void RecreateTxtControls(string ctrlPrefix, string ctrlType)
    {
        string[] ctrls = Request.Form.ToString().Split('&');
        int cnt = FindOccurence(ctrlPrefix);
        if (cnt > 0)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= cnt; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ctrls.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ctrls[i].Contains(ctrlPrefix + "-" + k.ToString()) && !ctrls[i].Contains("EVENTTARGET"))
                    {
                        string ctrlID = ctrls[i].Split('=')[0];

                        if (ctrlType == "TextBox")
                        {
                            CreateTextBox(ctrlID);
                        }

                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void RecreateDDLControls(string ctrlPrefix, string ctrlType)
    {
        string[] ctrls = Request.Form.ToString().Split('&');
        int cnt = FindOccurence(ctrlPrefix);
        if (cnt > 0)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= cnt; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ctrls.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ctrls[i].Contains(ctrlPrefix + "-" + k.ToString()) && !ctrls[i].Contains("EVENTTARGET"))
                    {
                        string ctrlID = ctrls[i].Split('=')[0];

                        if (ctrlType == "DropDownList")
                        {
                            CreateDropDownList(ctrlID);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void RecreateChkControls(string ctrlPrefix, string ctrlType)
    {
        string[] ctrls = Request.Form.ToString().Split('&');
        // ctrlPrefix = "chkDynamic";
        int cnt = FindOccurenceCheckbox(ctrlPrefix);
        if (cnt > 0)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= cnt; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ctrls.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ctrls[i].Contains(ctrlPrefix + "-" + k.ToString()) && !ctrls[i].Contains("EVENTTARGET"))
                    {
                        string ctrlID = ctrls[i].Split('=')[0];

                        if (ctrlType == "CheckBox")
                        {
                            CreateCheckbox(ctrlID);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReqFieldValidator(string ctrlPrefix, string ctrlType)
    {
        string[] ctrls = Request.Form.ToString().Split('&');
        // ctrlPrefix = "chkDynamic";
        int cnt = FindOccurenceCheckbox(ctrlPrefix);
        if (cnt > 0)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= cnt; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ctrls.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ctrls[i].Contains(ctrlPrefix + "-" + k.ToString()) && !ctrls[i].Contains("EVENTTARGET"))
                    {
                        string ctrlID = ctrls[i].Split('=')[0];

                        if (ctrlType == "RequiredFieldValidator")
                        {
                            CreateCheckbox(ctrlID);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReqLabel(string ctrlPrefix, string ctrlType)
    {
        string[] ctrls = Request.Form.ToString().Split('&');
        int cnt = FindOccurenceCheckbox(ctrlPrefix);
        if (cnt > 0)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= cnt; k++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ctrls.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ctrls[i].Contains(ctrlPrefix + "-" + k.ToString()) && !ctrls[i].Contains("EVENTTARGET"))
                    {
                        string ctrlID = ctrls[i].Split('=')[0];

                        if (ctrlType == "Label")
                        {
                            CreateLabel(ctrlID);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    private void CreateLabel(string ID)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.ID = ID;
        lbl.Text = "text";
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(lbl);
        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br />";
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(lt);
    }
    private void CreateTextBox(string ID)
    {
        //CreateLabel(ID);
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = ID;
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(txt);
        // txt.AutoPostBack = true;
        // txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(OnTextChanged);
        RequiredFieldValidator req = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        req.ControlToValidate = txt.ID;
        req.EnableViewState = false;

        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(txt);
        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br />";

    }


    private void CreateCheckbox(string ID)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.ID = ID;
        chk.Checked = true;
        chk.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chk_CheckedChanged);
        chk.AutoPostBack = true;
        chk.EnableViewState = false;
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(chk);
        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br />";
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(lt);
    }

    void chk_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    private void CreateDropDownList(string ID)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.ID = ID;
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", ""));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("One", "1"));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Two", "2"));
        ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Three", "3"));
        // ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
        ddl.EnableViewState = false;
        // ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(OnSelectedIndexChanged);
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(ddl);

        //int cnt2 = FindOccurence("CheckBox");
        //CreateCheckbox("CheckBox-" + Convert.ToString(cnt2 + 1));

        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br />";
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(lt);
    }

    private void CreateRequiredFieldValidator(string ID)
    {
        RequiredFieldValidator req = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        req.ID = ID;
        // ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
        // ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(OnSelectedIndexChanged);
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(req);
        Literal lt = new Literal();
        lt.Text = "<br />";
        pnlTextBox.Controls.Add(lt);
    }

    protected void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
        string ID = txt.ID;
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", "<script type = 'text/javascript'>alert('" + ID + " fired OnTextChanged event');</script>");
        //Place the functionality here
    }

    protected void ddlDynamic_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlcontrols.SelectedValue == "Textbox")
        {
            int cnt = FindOccurence("txtDynamic");
            CreateTextBox("txtDynamic-" + Convert.ToString(cnt + 1));

            int cntChk = FindOccurenceCheckbox("CheckBoxdll");
            CreateCheckbox("chkDynamic-" + Convert.ToString(cntChk + 1));
        }
        if (ddlcontrols.SelectedValue == "Dropdown")
        {
            int cnt = FindOccurence("ddlDynamic");
            CreateDropDownList("ddlDynamic-" + Convert.ToString(cnt + 1));

            int cntChk = FindOccurenceCheckbox("chkDynamic");
            CreateCheckbox("chkDynamic-" + Convert.ToString(cntChk + 1));


        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is. Your code is clearly creating all controls of one type at once, so that is what I would expect to see in your page output.

If you want to interleave controls then you need to change your algorithm to process controls one by one instead of by type.